# Django Forms displays incorrectly

Tags: python, django

Currently trying to create a questionnaire in Django, i have a forms.py like so and is causing issues in terms of how it displays

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Question, Question1_CHOICES,Question2_CHOICES


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']


class QuestionForm1(forms.ModelForm):
    Q1 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        choices=Question1_CHOICES
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['question1', 'question2',]
        widgets = {
            'question': forms.RadioSelect()
        }


class QuestionForm2(forms.ModelForm):
    Q2 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        choices=Question2_CHOICES

    )
```

With this code [I get a display problem like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2aNq.png) , im not sure how to correct it and i feel the problem lies withing my forms.py file. But my choices are inside my models.py which i can send if needed.

The questions should be on separate pages and both HTML documents link to there required QuestionForm to make that display the questions but, on page one im seeing both Q1 & Q2 and im not sure why

Comment: Please specify what the problem is. I can see the image, but how exactly is it wrong?

Comment: Maybe you missed the `class Meta` inside `QuestionForm2`?

Comment: @jonKiparsky I have drop down boxes on the first page of my questionnaire.  These should only be radio buttons. and question2 should not be shown on the first page. hope that helps

Comment: @nik_m we keep meeting like this. I've called it within that Meta class and it does post to the database which is the confusing thing. but it's not using the radio buttons it only accepts Posts to the database from the drop-down boxes.

Comment: Oh. Now I get it. You render the whole form (all 3 fields, `question1`, `question2` and `Q1`) because you use it like this in your templates `{{ form }}`. That's ok. If you want to render them separately do it like `{{ form.Q1 }}` etc.

Comment: Again thanks for the help @nik_m

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `QuestionForm1` should be updated to this, in order to render them as radio buttons:

```
class QuestionForm1(forms.ModelForm):
    Q1 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        choices=Question1_CHOICES
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['question1', 'question2',]
        widgets = {
            'question1': forms.RadioSelect(),
            'question2': forms.RadioSelect(),
        }
```